# rbenvインストールの際のエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

rbenvのインストールする際に、

```
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

の後、以下のエラーが発生。

```
-bash: eval: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 1: `“export PATH="/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}" >export RBENV_SHELL=bash source 
'/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.1/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash' command >rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null rbenv() { local command command="$1" if [ "$#" ->gt 0 ]; then shift fi case "$command" in rehash|shell) eval "$(rbenv 
"sh-$command" "$@")";; *) command rbenv "$command" "$@";; esac }”'
```

ご教授お願いいたします！　ちなみに、

```
$ rbenv init -
```

を実行した結果は、

```
export PATH="/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"
export RBENV_SHELL=bash
source '/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.1/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash'
command rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null
rbenv() {
  local command
  command="$1"
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
  fi

  case "$command" in
  rehash|shell)
    eval "$(rbenv "sh-$command" "$@")";;
  *)
    command rbenv "$command" "$@";;
  esac
}
```

となりました。

Comment: エラーを、 改行をほどよく扱ってくれる quote 引用ではなく、そのままを張り付ける block 引用 (一番最初の、 実行したコマンドと同じ形式) で記載をお願いできますでしょうか。 また、 `rbenv init -` を実行すると、何が表示されますでしょうか。

Comment: エラーメッセージが `“(U+201C)` と `”(U+201D)` で囲われている様に見受けられるのですが、もしかして、ダブルクォート(`"`)ではなくて `“` と `”` で `$(rbenv init)` を囲んでいないでしょうか？ つまり、`echo 'eval “$(rbenv init -)”' >> ~/.bash_profile` としている可能性があります。

Comment: @metropolis ご指摘のとおりでした！ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

`$(rbenv init -)` が、ダブルクォート `"` ではなく、`“` (U+201C) と `”` (U+201D) で囲われてしまっています。特に macOS だと、入力の際にこの変換が起こる「スマート引用符」の機能によって勝手に変換されてしまう場合があるため、注意が必要です（オプションで無効にできます）。

-- [metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis) さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/36649/rbenv%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC#comment36668_36649)より